# React Hook: how would you rewrite this old code using React Hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have `componentDidMount` method calls `this.initializeSelections()` and
`this.initalizeSelections()` has the following implementation inside the method.

```
initializeSelections = () => {
   this.setState({
     selectedRetailers: this.getAllConnectedRetailerIds(),
     selectedPriceTypes: this.getDefaultRetailerPriceTypes(),
   })
}
```

I am trying to wrap my head around how you would write this if I were to rewrite this using React Hook and I feel stuck.. This is what I have so far and it does not look anywhere close to the working code.

```
 useEffect( () => {
   initializeSelections()
 }, [selectedRetailers, selectedPriceTypes])`
```

const initializeSection = () => {
    I am not sure how to use useState here...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UseEffect with an empty dependency array will be the same as componentDidMount().

With useEffect if you have functions inside of useEffect you may get an exhaustive-deps warning.  There are several different ways to go about dealing with that.  They will give you examples in the warning or you can wrap your functions in a useCallback hook to deal with this.  Or if your sure you don't need the dependencies then you can disable this warning or ignore it.

You have to use the useState hook if you want to set the state with hooks.  So your component would look like the following:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [selectedRetailers, setSelectedRetailers] = useState(yourIntialValue);
  const [selectedPriceTypes, setselectedPriceTypes] = useState(yourIntialValue);

  useEffect( () => {
   setSelectedRetailers(getAllConnectedRetailerIds());
   setSelectedPriceTypes(getDefaultRetailerPriceTypes());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}
```

Also you can also set up useState similar to the class based state object like so:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  //your state values
  selectedRetailers: initialValue,
  selectedPriceTypes: initialValue,
});
```

Then you can setState like so:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  selectedRetailers: newValue,
  selectedPriceTypes: newValue
});
```